# Dojo js toolkit: Problem with dynamically filled select

Tags: javascript, html, select, dynamic, dojo

I'm having some issues with dijit.form.Select items.

In a page i have two of these items: one is filled while the html page is being loaded and the other one is filled depending on which option the user has selected on the first one.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about (now I'm keeping the code simple, but in the real version I've included all the necessary dojo modules and libraries in the head section):

```
<html> 
        <head> 
                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                        function updateB(val){ 

                                var menu = dojo.byId("selB"); 

                                menu.options.lenght=0; 

                                if(val=="aaa") 
                                        menu.addOption({value: "aa", label: "aa"}); 
                                else 
                                        menu.addOption({value: "bb", label: "bb"}); 
                        } 
                </script> 
        </head> 

        <body> 
                <select id="selA" name="selA" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" style="width: 180px;" onchange="updateB(this.get('value'));"></select> 

                <select id="selB" name="selB" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" style="width: 180px; "></select> 

                <script type="text/javascript"> 
                        var menu = dojo.byId("selA"); 

                        menu.addOption({value: "aaa", label: "aaa"},{value: "bbb", label: "bbb"}); 

                </script> 

        </body> 

</html>
```

When I load the page in my browser, menu selA contains the options aaa and bbb. But selB, whenether I select aaa or bbb in selA remains empty. In javascript error console i can read: dojo.byId [undefined] is not a function. I've spent a lot of time trying to make this work (tryied a lot of alternatives) but had no luck. I can only manage to fill dojo select on onload events, not on onchange (associated with another select) or onclick (associated to a button). With standard HTML select items everything works ok instead. 
What can I do in order to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is more or less your working example

```
<html> 
    <head> 
            <link href="js/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="isDebug: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript"> 
                    dojo.require("dijit.form.Select");
                    function updateB(val){ 
                            var menu = dijit.byId("selB"); 
                            menu.options.lenght=0; 
                            if(val=="aaa") 
                                    menu.addOption({value: "aa", label: "aa"}); 
                            else 
                                    menu.addOption({value: "bb", label: "bb"}); 
                    } 
                    dojo.addOnLoad(function()
                    {
                        var menu = dijit.byId("selA"); 
                        menu.addOption([{value: "aaa", label: "aaa"},{value: "bbb", label: "bbb"}]); 
                    });
            </script> 
    </head> 

    <body> 
            <select id="selA" name="selA" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" style="width: 180px;" onchange="updateB(this.get('value'));"></select> 
            <select id="selB" name="selB" dojoType="dijit.form.Select" style="width: 180px; "></select> 
    </body>
```

What I have changed:

- moved code that setup selA Select to
  dojo.addOnLoad. This is required,
  because previously when you were tried
  to get selA widget it wasn't fully
  created and dojo couldn't return its
  widget yet. Dojo create its widgets
  after page is fully loaded. After
  it creates everything it calls
  addOnLoad function. So you should
  place in this function all your
  initialization stuff.
- Select is a dijit kind of widget so
  dijit.byId should be used instead of
  dojo.byId.